# How to populate a cell with a comma separated list version of a list-like text?

Tags: worksheet-function, csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, list

Suppose I have the following data in a cell (note: list-like text with minus signs and line breaks):

```
- val1
- val2
- val3
```

How can I populate another cell with a comma separated list version of the above-mentioned list-like text?

That is, I would like to have something like this in cell B1:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | list-like text above | val1, val2, val3 |

---

**Bonus 1**

And what about making something similar the above example but from this list-like text (note: "string:" added)

```
string: 
- val1
- val2
- val3
```

to this in cell B1?

```
- string: val1, val2, val3
```

---

**Bonus 2**

And from this list-like text (note: multiple "string:" added)

```
stringA: 
- val1A
- val2A
- val3A
stringB: 
- val1B
- val2B
- val3B
```

to this in cell B1?

```
- stringA: val1A, val2A, val3C
- stringB: val1B, val2B, val3C
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I am almost new to LibreOffice Calc and I don't know where to start for this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty: combine two REGEXes to remove trailing minus signs, replace line breaks by commata. Put the following Formula in B1 to get the desired result:

```
=REGEX(REGEX(A1;"\n- ";", ";"g"); "- "; "")
```

Here's the same formula with explanations:

```
=REGEX(                # Outer regex: removes trailing "-"
    REGEX(             # Inner regex: replaces line feed followed by "- "
       A1;             # Text to transform
       "\n- ";         # Regex pattern: Line feed followed by "- "
       ", ";           # Replacement
       "g"             # Flag: global
    );                 # End of inner Regex; result is input text for outer regex
    "- ";              # Regex pattern (plain text "- ")
    ""                 # Replacement: delete matching text
 )
```

I've combined two regexes since the "\n- " doesn't match the "-" sign before val1. So, the "inner regex" handles line breaks and minus signs of val2 and val3; the "outer regex" handles the minus sign before val1.

Comment: +1 I have never noticed the REGEX function in LibreOffice Calc. Wish it would also exist in Excel.

Comment: Thanks @tohuwawohu. It works! I just updated the question with a slightly more complicated case

Comment: @Backo: Please try it first yourself. It can be solved the same way as the initial question.

Comment: I tried and found for "Bonus 1" this weird formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(REGEX(REGEX(A1;"\n- ";", ";"g");"- ";"");":,";":")`